# Ruby 3.2.3 rake does not seem to work - or something. Rake aborted! cannot load such file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rake

So I'm trying to learn Ruby and rails from Lynda.com When I get to the database sections the teacher has us do this schema dump with rake but it aborts and I cant figure out whats wrong (I'm very new to all this so please forgive me =))

OS: Lion
Ruby: ruby 1.9.3p194 (2012-04-20 revision 35410) [x86_64-darwin11.3.0]
Rails: Rails 3.2.3
Rake: rake (0.9.2.2)
$PATH: /usr/local/Cellar:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/mysql/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11/bin

All the gems should be up to date ( just reinstalled the other day ). If you need to know anything else to help troubleshoot please let me know!

This is the errors I'm getting:

```
Alex$ rake db:schema:dump
rake aborted!
cannot load such file -- bundler/setup

(See full trace by running task with --trace)


Alex$ rake --trace
rake aborted!
cannot load such file -- bundler/setup
/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
/Users/Alex/Sites/simple_cms/config/boot.rb:6:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
/Users/Alex/Sites/simple_cms/config/application.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
/Users/Alex/Sites/simple_cms/Rakefile:5:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake/rake_module.rb:25:in `load'
/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake/rake_module.rb:25:in `load_rakefile'
/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake/application.rb:501:in `raw_load_rakefile'
/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake/application.rb:82:in `block in load_rakefile'
/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake/application.rb:133:in `standard_exception_handling'
/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake/application.rb:81:in `load_rakefile'
/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake/application.rb:65:in `block in run'
/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake/application.rb:133:in `standard_exception_handling'
/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake/application.rb:63:in `run'
/usr/local/bin/rake:32:in `<main>'
```

Got this when I tried to reinstall budel and run this command:

```
Alex$ bundle exec rake db:schema:dump
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/mysql2-0.3.11/lib/mysql2/mysql2.bundle: [BUG] Segmentation fault
ruby 1.9.3p194 (2012-04-20 revision 35410) [x86_64-darwin11.3.0]

-- Control frame information -----------------------------------------------
c:0030 p:-17562901266652 s:0090 b:0090 l:000089 d:000089 TOP   
c:0029 p:---- s:0088 b:0088 l:000087 d:000087 CFUNC  :require
c:0028 p:0119 s:0084 b:0084 l:000083 d:000083 TOP    /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/mysql2-0.3.11/lib/mysql2.rb:9
c:0027 p:---- s:0082 b:0082 l:000081 d:000081 FINISH
c:0026 p:---- s:0080 b:0080 l:000079 d:000079 CFUNC  :require
c:0025 p:0026 s:0076 b:0076 l:000056 d:000075 BLOCK  /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.1.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:68
c:0024 p:---- s:0073 b:0073 l:000072 d:000072 FINISH
c:0023 p:---- s:0071 b:0071 l:000070 d:000070 CFUNC  :each
c:0022 p:0091 s:0068 b:0068 l:000056 d:000067 BLOCK  /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.1.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:66
c:0021 p:---- s:0062 b:0062 l:000061 d:000061 FINISH
c:0020 p:---- s:0060 b:0060 l:000059 d:000059 CFUNC  :each
c:0019 p:0046 s:0057 b:0057 l:000056 d:000056 METHOD /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.1.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:55
c:0018 p:0021 s:0053 b:0053 l:000052 d:000052 METHOD /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.1.3/lib/bundler.rb:119
c:0017 p:0089 s:0049 b:0049 l:000048 d:000048 TOP    /Users/Alex/Sites/simple_cms/config/application.rb:7
c:0016 p:---- s:0047 b:0047 l:000046 d:000046 FINISH
c:0015 p:---- s:0045 b:0045 l:000044 d:000044 CFUNC  :require
c:0014 p:0026 s:0041 b:0041 l:000040 d:000040 TOP    /Users/Alex/Sites/simple_cms/Rakefile:5
c:0013 p:---- s:0039 b:0039 l:000038 d:000038 FINISH
c:0012 p:---- s:0037 b:0037 l:000036 d:000036 CFUNC  :load
c:0011 p:0013 s:0033 b:0033 l:000032 d:000032 METHOD /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/rake_module.rb:25
c:0010 p:0274 s:0029 b:0029 l:000028 d:000028 METHOD /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:501
c:0009 p:0009 s:0024 b:0024 l:000017 d:000023 BLOCK  /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:82
c:0008 p:0009 s:0022 b:0022 l:000021 d:000021 METHOD /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:133
c:0007 p:0011 s:0018 b:0018 l:000017 d:000017 METHOD /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:81
c:0006 p:0019 s:0015 b:0015 l:000008 d:000014 BLOCK  /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:65
c:0005 p:0009 s:0013 b:0013 l:000012 d:000012 METHOD /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:133
c:0004 p:0011 s:0009 b:0009 l:000008 d:000008 METHOD /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:63
c:0003 p:0048 s:0006 b:0006 l:0003a8 d:000a48 EVAL   /usr/local/bin/rake:32
c:0002 p:---- s:0004 b:0004 l:000003 d:000003 FINISH
c:0001 p:0000 s:0002 b:0002 l:0003a8 d:0003a8 TOP
```

......

```
[NOTE]
You may have encountered a bug in the Ruby interpreter or extension libraries.
Bug reports are welcome.
For details: http://www.ruby-lang.org/bugreport.html

Abort trap: 6
Alex$
```

The error is to long to fit into this field.

Comment: Do you have bundler installed?

Comment: I saw in some of the other topics about this that rake should be in the rails project gemfile but its not mentioned in mine, if that matters...

Answer (score 0):

I've resolved this by running:

```
gem install bundler
```

If you try that and it shows you have bundler installed, try typing:

```
bundle exec rake db:schema:dump
```

You may be running the command outside the scope of the current bundle.

Here's a bit more background information on why you need to add `bundle exec` in front of your rake commands:

http://gembundler.com/

Also, note that `rake` isn't required in your 'Gemfile' as long as you have `rails` specified. `rake` installs as a dependency of `rails`. To see the correlation, take a look at your `Gemfile.lock`.

Once you install rvm, add the following to a file named `.rvmrc` in the root directory of your project:

```
if [[ -d "${rvm_path:-$HOME/.rvm}/environments" \
  && -s "${rvm_path:-$HOME/.rvm}/environments/ruby-1.9.3-p125@MYPROJECTNAME" ]] ; then
  \. "${rvm_path:-$HOME/.rvm}/environments/ruby-1.9.3-p125@MYPROJECTNAME"  
else
  rvm --create use  "ruby-1.9.3-p125@MYPROJECTNAME"
fi
```

Substitute your project name for "MYPROJECTNAME" and the appropriate ruby version where you see `ruby-1.9.3-p125`. Then when you change into that directory, rvm will automatically set the gemset and ruby version for you.

Comment: Wow I got a lot of Erros for doing that. Please see the update in the original post!

Comment: The next step I'd take would be to instal rvm -- it'll manage a lot of this for you so you don't have to worry. See https://rvm.io/

Answer (score 0):

Install rvm

Create a new gemset for ur project. Im betting youre using aystem ruby that comes with Lion in some regards

Comment: I'm sorry could you be more explicit? What do I do after I make a new gem set, reinstall ruby gem and then rails? Do I have to "activate" this new gem set first? Sorry I'm very new to all of this so the more info the better, you know?

Comment: Install rvm first. Than follow its instructions to set up a default ruby enviroment.

Comment: Than youd update rubygems with rvm and create a new gemset while in your project directory, there are good instructions on the googles to do this....

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be that I installed bundle after I installed ruby & rails. I uninstalled ruby and all my gems (but left bundle and homebrew) and then used rvm to install the latest ruby and rails.

**Also note I did not use sudo unless it required me to. I think this put the files in a different place and that might have also helped.**

rake commands are now working (with out using the bundle command before it).

**So basically I had bundle installed and then did everything this guy did at the bottom of his questions ( #5 gave me and error and did not install ).**

[How do you install (build) Ruby 1.9.3 on OSX Lion?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9626729/how-do-you-install-build-ruby-1-9-3-on-osx-lion)

Hope this helps anyone else running into the same problem I did.